# Adding form elements with jquery to a drupal form

Tags: forms, javascript

I have a recipe form under node.  Up until now, I had a button that would add another ingredient textfield by updating that section of the form with an ajax call.  I can no longer do this.

Now I have a button on my form that instantly adds ingredient fields to a form without making a call to the server.  The problem is even though the new fields are attached to my ingredient table, the server will not process these new fields.

Is there a way to get Drupal to recognize that I have added fields to a form and show this on the form_state?  Thank you!  any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use Drupal's default handling of adding multivalue fields? Are you trying to prepopulate a multivalue field from another source?

Comment: I am not sure what Drupal's method is.  I cant use the ajax method because if this section of the form is rebuilt I will lose all of the data I originally had in it.  Even though the text is kept, the highlights, numbers, and other data is lost.  I would have to make the javascript run all of that information again which is doable but I don't know how efficient that is.

Comment: The drupal method is just to select 'number of values' in the field settings, if you set it to 'unlimited' it will add a button to add another field on the node form.

Comment: I think what I am going to do is use an Ajax call, but I am going to turn off form rebuild.  This way the array is updated server side and the javascript will update it client side.